# Cannot find a version that satisfy the requirment torch

Tags: python, pytorch

As i input the code from pytroch pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
This show: e:\python3.7>pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

I am using a python 3.7 so that is not a problem. I don't know why this happen.

I search simialr case but I didn't find the one I am facing.

Comment: What is the full traceback when you run `python3 -u -m pip install torch -vvv` command?

Comment: thanks for answering, the problem was solved. Somehow I install 32bit python which is not compatible. I changed it to 64-bit and it works now.